# Updating bash against shellshock on Linux Mint 16

Tags: bash, linux-mint, shellshock

Apparently the LM package manager person is on holiday, so even an up-to-date Mint 16 box is vulnerable to the original Shellshock CVE.  How do you update such a system meanwhile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Linux Mint 16 [reached end of support/life in July 2014](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Linux_Mint_releases#Release_history)¹, you should consider upgrading, as other (security) issues in that version will not be resolved either.

Since Mint 16 is based on Ubuntu 13.10, the same advice as [Deim0s gave for Ubuntu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/157684/33055) applies for you.

¹ <sub>If it wasn't, you would probably just be able to update bash from the original Ubuntu repository, the LM package manager being on holiday or not, except for Ubuntu 13.10 being EOL as well (which is **not** a coincidence</sub>

Comment: Didn't realize that.  Considering 16 was the newest version available when I installed it in May, well...that was quick...